# Ошибка с оператором &: "object of type 'generator' has no len()"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, булева-алгебра

Когда пишу вот так, то все работает:

```
np.random.seed(242)
s = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=100) ** 3, index=[x * 3 for x in range(100)])
print(s[(x % 2 != 0 for x in s.index) & (s < 2.6)].sum())
```

Но если изменить `and` на `&` выдает такую ошибку:

> object of type 'generator' has no len()

У меня ведь нет `len()`, в чем дело?

Comment: А где у вас в коде and?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть ошибки в том, что вы пытаетесь использовать оператор **побитого И** (`&`) по отношению к `generator` и `pandas.Series`:

```
In [54]: type( (x % 2 != 0 for x in s.index) )
Out[54]: generator

In [55]: type( (s < 2.6) )
Out[55]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

---

попробуйте так:

```
In [41]: s[(s.index % 2 != 0) & (s < 2.6)].sum()
Out[41]: -15.150748101821666
```

если есть непреодолимое желание использовать циклы (что в Pandas чаще всего считается "моветоном"), то замените генератор на `list comprehension`:

```
In [46]: s[([x % 2 != 0 for x in s.index]) & (s < 2.6)].sum()
# NOTE:---> ^                           ^
Out[46]: -15.150748101821666
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало